# Is there a way to change textView when a particular image(drawable) appears?

Tags: java, android

I am testing this code that generates a random image, and I am trying to make each generated image have a description

```
Button buttong;
Random r;

Integer[] images = {
        R.drawable.img250, R.drawable.img484, R.drawable.img485,
};

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    buttong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttong);
    r = new Random()


    buttong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setImageResource(images[r.nextInt(images.length)]);             
        }
    });
```

I dont know how to explain this very well, but for example: when the image "img250" appears put something like "message.setText("Miami Beach is a south Florida island city");"

i tried if/else statement but no luck

Comment: "i tried if/else statement but no luck" – Please show us that `if`-`else`, so we know exactly how it's not working for you.

Comment: @MikeM. probably wrong but the one I tested that didn't answer error was this
 if(r.nextInt(images.length) == R.drawable.img250){
                    message.setText(R.string.text2);
                }

Comment: First, set the image with `yourImageView.setImage[Bitmap|Drawable|Resource](image)`instead of setting it via xml then modify your textview.

Comment: Please edit the question to put your answer to Mike's question in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the if statement you posted in the comments, it looks like you were choosing one random image when you set the image and another when you were setting the text. Choose the image first, and then use that to both set the image and the text.

For example:

```
Integer randomResource = images[r.nextInt(images.length)];
imageView.setImageResource(randomResource );
if (randomResource == R.drawable.img250) {
   message.setText("Miami Beach is a south Florida island city");
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much!
I will try to learn more about. thx

Comment: @kapp, I'm glad it works. Could you please edit your question to add the if statement you were originally trying to use, to improve the quality of the question?